# How to install PyAutoGui on python3 64 bit on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10, pyautogui

I've tried:

```
pip install pyautogui

#output:

  File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install pyautogui
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried

```
C:\Python34\pip.exe install pyautogui

#output:

  File "<stdin>", line 1
C:\Python34\pip.exe install pyautogui
                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

None of these are working. Again, I'm on Windows 10, I have python 3, and python is 64 bit not 32 bit.

Comment: See my answer bellow and let me know if you'r still experiencing a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pip` you are trying to use is not a python package or [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). `pip` is instead a package management system for `Python`. The `python3` distribution should already come with `pip` pre-installed.

Use the `pip` command on the command-line. Running `pip -h` will give you a quick discription of which commands you can use. See the image bellow:

[image]

If you can replicate the image above in your command-line, it means you already have pip installed and can go ahead and run `$ pip install pyautogui`.

If instead you get something like:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

it means you need to [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) first.

Answer (score 2):

install using anaconda:

- download anaconda from its website
- then type `pip install pyautogui`
  in anaconda command prompt

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip install pyautogui`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58843904/edit) to add an explanation of what your code is doing, why it works, and how it differs from the other answers. Posts without such info tends to be downvoted or removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can download conda at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyautogui 

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyautogui
```

OR
    pip install pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

Enter into `cmd`. It works for me as of python 3.8.

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```